# Which of the following statements best explain line 115 and 116 in the image below?

Tags: python-3.x, list

1.The item's number is the index of the shopping list corresponding to looking for.

2.The index of item in shopping list corresponds to looking for.

```
shopping_list = ["milk", "rice", "milo", "oats", "oil", "bread", "eggs"]
looking_for = "oil".lower()
found = None

for item in range(len(shopping_list)):
    if shopping_list[item] == looking_for:
        found = item
        break

if looking_for in shopping_list:
    found = shopping_list.index(looking_for)

print(f"Item found at position {found}")
```

Comment: Are lines 115 and 116 necessary?

Comment: You show an image of code and text output. Please include that as text and not image. Independent of that : How is this not a homework question? What is your own thought on how to answer and why?

Comment: It's not a homework question Sir. I'm new to python and I have come across that code (line 115 and 116) several times in different examples in most of the you tube tutorials without clearly explaining it. I want to know which of my comments best explain that line.

Comment: Lines 121 - 122 pretty much does what 115 to 118 does.   So I'm not entirely sure the point of this question.  Since you used ```item``` as the index, it's confusing me when I read your two statements.